# How can I make the exceeding submenu area open based on the right edge of the parent items?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, pseudo-element

I'm building a simple horizontal menu with some sub-menus.

But I'm stuck trying to make the sub-items respect the width of the parent items.

Here some images what I'm talking about:

Here's what I get:

[image]

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnr4anfx/)

Check it out:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  float: left;
}
.menu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
.menu li a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.menu li:hover ul,
.menu li.over ul {
  display: block;
}
.menu li ul li {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul class="menu">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">What we do?</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">What we do? 01</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">What we do? 02</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">What we do? 03</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Links</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Myotherwebsiteiscool</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Form Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Find us</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: 
http://i.imgur.com/OSSr8oc.png
http://i.imgur.com/UML83Xp.png

Comment: You'll need javascript for that....CSS can't detect that the submenu will overflow the page...only JS can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the css here- note that I've change `left: 0` to `right: 0`

```
.menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

check it out:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  float: left;
}
.menu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
.menu li a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.menu li:hover ul,
.menu li.over ul {
  display: block;
}
.menu li ul li {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul class="menu">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">What we do?</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">What we do? 01</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">What we do? 02</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">What we do? 03</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Links</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Myotherwebsiteiscool</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Form Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Find us</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: But in this case, if I set submenus to my HOME or ABOUT button, the submenu will overflow the left edge of parent menu!

Comment: Update that CSS to not be applied to the children of the first element in the menu...